# How to run a command block in the main shell?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I try to run a series of commands as a whole inside the main shell, but the way I was teached only works inside the subshell:

```
 echo $BASHPID
18884
 (echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep 5;echo "hello again $BASHPID")
hello 22268
hello again 22268
```

I also tried:

```
. (echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep 5;echo "hello again $BASHPID")
source (echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep 5;echo "hello again $BASHPID")
```

to use the source command, because I learned it forces the script to run inside the main shell.

I guess, it would work, if I put the commands inside a file and run it with the source command, but I would like to know if there is a way beyound a script file.

Comment: What prevents you from doing `echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep 5;echo "hello again $BASHPID"` ?

Comment: I would like to know if I can put the three commands into a block and execute this block inside the main shall, moreover I would like to know if it makes sense to want it or if it contradicts some shell logic.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you you explain what your application goal is (I mean, it's a good thing to discover how shell mechanics work, but for which task do you want it and why you use `()` anyhow)

Comment: my understanding of shell, subshells and jobs is too vague. I thought, maybe this could clarify it. for instance, my understanding of (echo "hi") is that it is run inside a subshell and (echo "hi")& is run inside a subshell, but the job is once again run in a further subshell. If there is a block command inside the shell to run the block inside the main shell then this block run as a job would run in a subshell, so basically the first job block is run inside the second subshell and the second job block is run inside the first. If this was true, I would had a less vague understanding.

Comment: Try `source` with: `source <(echo 'echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep .5;echo "hello again $BASHPID"')`

Comment: You should maybe get a look at: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FullBashGuide  and then the really good read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls   (and also when needed: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ )  : these are good starting point to learn the shell and avoid common pitfalls

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `( something )`, which launches `something` in a subshell, use `{ something ; }`, which launches `something` in the current shell

You need spaces after the `{`, and should also have a `;` (or a newline) before the `}`.

Ex:

```
$ { echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep 5;echo "hello again $BASHPID" ; }
hello 3536
hello again 3536
```

Please note however that if you launch some complex commands (or piped commands), those will be in a subshell most of the time anyway.

And the "portable" way to get your current shell's pid is `$$`.

So I'd instead write your test as:

```
{ echo "hello $$"; sleep 5 ; echo "hello again $$" ; }
```

(the sleep is not really useful anyway here)

Comment: I get an error massage:

Comment:  {echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep 5;echo "hello again $BASHPID"}
No command '{echo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'aecho' from package 'netatalk' (universe)
 Command 'echo' from package 'coreutils' (main)
{echo: command not found
hello again 18884}

Comment: @sharkant : you need a ";" before the closing "}"

Comment: and you should use:  echo $$  instead, to have your current shell's pid, imo.

Comment:  {echo "hello $BASHPID";sleep 5;echo "hello again $BASHPID";}
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Comment: @sharkant:  please show me :  ps -ef | grep $$ | grep -v grep

Comment: @sharkant you need spaces after initial { and before closing } too ...

Comment: space is needed only after opening  '{ ' , and a semicolon before closing ';}' that's only if your codeblock in one line ! which mean a new line makes semicolon useless

Comment: @youness: I said so in my answer... ( but I corrected the (mis-)info about "space before '}' " , thanks)

Comment: Note that `$$` contains the pid of the process that executed the shell interpreter. It doesn't change in subshells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: indeed :/ this will not check what the poster wants to check... that one-liner is really useless as-is ^^   ( I'm also wondering about the need for a space after "{", is it to differentiate a command grouping from a  {a,b} expansion? (I can't find the exact term... the one expanding before echoing in : `echo a{b,c}` ? )

Comment: It's because `{` is a keyword. Same reason you need a space or other token delimiter (`(`, `<`, ... would also do) after `while` or `for` or `[[`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: that is a nice and simple clarification :) thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Depends what you mean by *as a whole*.

If you only mean send several commands to the shell, and make sure the shell doesn't start running them until you've entered them all, then you can just do:

```
cmd1; cmd2
```

Or

```
cmd1Ctrl+VCtrl+Jcmd2
```

(or enable bracketed-paste (`bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on'`) and paste the commands from a terminal that supports bracketed paste).

Or:

```
{
cmd1
cmd2
}
```

To have them on several lines.

If you want to group them so they share the same stdin or stdout for instance, you could use:

```
{ cmd1; cmd2; } < in > out
```

Or

```
eval 'cmd1; cmd2' < in > out
```

If you want them to run with their own variable and option scope, as `bash` doesn't have the equivalent of `zsh` anonymous functions, you'd need to define a temporary function:

```
f() { local var; var=foo; bar;}; f
```

Comment: this is very interesting:{ cmd1; cmd2; } < in > out

Comment: @sharkant: You can't have better source of infos than Stephane, imo ^^ (and you should probably re-attribute the 'accepted answer' checkmark ! ). See also Stephane's answers on his profile ... lots to be learned (but maybe, for you, in a little while, after you read things such as the starting point urls I gave in a comment on your post?). (Gosh, I really sound like a fan, don't I ? ...)